# powershell Get-Content and .Net Open() handing path differently

Tags: powershell

Get-Content appears to use the current working directory location to resolve realative paths. However, the .Net System.Io.File Open() method does not. What is the PowerShell-centric way to resolve a relative path for .Net?

```
PS C:\src\t> type .\ReadWays.ps1
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$Path
)
Write-Host "Path is $Path"
Get-Content -Path $Path | Out-Null
if ([System.IO.StreamReader]$sr = [System.IO.File]::Open($Path, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)) { $sr.Close() }

PS C:\src\t> .\ReadWays.ps1 -Path '.\t.txt'
Path is .\t.txt
MethodInvocationException: C:\src\t\ReadWays.ps1:8
Line |
   8 |  if ([System.IO.StreamReader]$sr = [System.IO.File]::Open($Path, [Syst …
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "Open" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\t.txt'."

PS C:\src\t> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works fine for me and is compatible with Windows
and Linux. This is using [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path?view=powershell-7.2) to resolve the relative paths. I was previously using [`Resolve-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path) which is incorrect, only the former resolves to *file-system-native* paths, thanks [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249827/powershell-get-content-and-net-open-handing-path-differently/70249984?noredirect=1#comment124592291_70249984) for pointing it out

```
param(
    [ValidateScript({ 
        if(Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf)
        {
            return $true
        }
        throw 'Invalid File Path'
    })]
    [string]$Path
)

if(-not $Path.StartsWith('\\'))
{
    [string]$Path = Convert-Path $Path
}

$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new(
    [System.IO.File]::Open(
        $Path, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open
    )
)

$reader.BaseStream
$reader.Close()
```

---

#### Last Edit

The following should be able to handle:

- UNC Paths
- Work on Windows and Linux
- Be efficient
- Handle Relative Paths

Starting from the base that `$Path` is valid thanks to the `ValidateScript attribute`, we only need to determine if the path we are dealing with is UNC, Relative or Absolute.

> UNC paths must always be fully qualified. They can include relative directory segments (. and ..), but these must be part of a fully qualified path. You can use relative paths only by mapping a UNC path to a drive letter.

We can assume a UNC path **must always** start with `\\`, so this condition should suffice to determine if `$Path` will be manipulated or not:

```
if(-not $Path.StartsWith('\\'))
```

Lastly, **in the `begin` block**, updating the environment's current directory each time our script or function runs with:

```
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $pwd.ProviderPath
```

By doing so, `([System.IO.FileInfo]$Path).FullName` should give us the absolute path of our parameter, be it UNC, Relative or Absolute.

```
param(
    [ValidateScript({ 
        if(Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf) {
            return $true
        }
        throw 'Invalid File Path'
    })] [string]$Path
)

begin
{
    [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $pwd.ProviderPath
}

process
{
    if(-not $Path.StartsWith('\\'))
    {
        $Path = ([System.IO.FileInfo]$Path).FullName
    }

    try
    {
        $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new(
            [System.IO.File]::Open(
                $Path, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open
            )
        )

        $reader.BaseStream
    }
    catch
    {
        $_.Exception.Message
    }
    finally
    {
        $reader.Close()
        $reader.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. It seems that assigning a string, `[Io.FileInfo]$Path = '.\t.txt'` does not produce the same thing as `[Io.FileInfo]$Path = Get-ChildItem -Path '.\t.txt'`. I had to change it to `::Open((Get-ChildItem -Path $Path).FullName,...`

Comment: I would be fine without .Net. My reason for using the .Net functions is speed performance.

Comment: Does there need to be a test using `Split-Path`? `Resolve-Path -Path "C:\src\t\t.txt` will return a fully qualified, rooted path.

Comment: I am selecting this answer since I believe just using `Resolve-Path`  is the most straightforward. It uses the PowerShell (not .NET) path which is what a PowerShell developer might expect.

Comment: @lit I have added a last edit to my answer in case you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a test to see if the path is relative and if so, convert it to absolute like:

```
if (![System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($Path) -or $Path -match '^\\[^\\]+') {
    $path =  [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($pwd, $Path))
}
```

<sup>I added `$Path -match '^\\[^\\]+'` to also convert relative paths starting with a backslash like `\ReadWays.ps1` meaning the path starts at the root directory. UNC paths that start with two backslashes are regarded as absolute.</sup>

Comment: This in combination with `Set-Location` and `Push-Location` not updating the value of `[io.directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()` answered my question too, you can post it on mine too :)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the issue with `\ `-rooted non-UNC paths, but note that if you want to resolve them correctly you can _not_ rely on `[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath()`, as it will again resolve relative to _.NET_'s working directory, which may be _on a different drive_.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common question.  Somehow .net and powershell don't agree on the current directory.

```
[System.IO.File]::Open("$pwd\$Path", [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
```

Comment: I am not sure that will work if $Path is already fully rooted.